# Android: доступ к API VK

Tags: java, android, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Как правильно достать данные авторизованного пользователя из ВКонтакте?
**Код ниже вылетает с ошибкой в логе:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String[] scope = new String[]{VKScope.MESSAGES, VKScope.FRIENDS, VKScope.WALL, VKScope.STATUS};
    private TextView textView1, textView2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String[] fingerprints = VKUtil.getCertificateFingerprint(this, this.getPackageName());
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(fingerprints));

        VKSdk.login(this, scope);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (!VKSdk.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data, new VKCallback<VKAccessToken>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(VKAccessToken res) {
                // Пользователь успешно авторизовался
                textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

                VKRequest request = VKApi.users().get(VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.FIELDS, "first_name,last_name"));

                request.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {

                        //VKList list = (VKList) response.parsedModel;
                        VKUsersArray list = (VKUsersArray) response.parsedModel;

                        for (VKApiUserFull userFull : list) {
                            textView1.setText(userFull.first_name);
                        }

                    }
                });
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Хорошо!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            @Override
            public void onError(VKError error) {
                // Произошла ошибка авторизации (например, пользователь запретил авторизацию)
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Плохо!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        })) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
 }
```

**Лог:**

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                           Process: com.example.gukov.testvk, PID: 4149
>                                                                           java.lang.ClassCastException: com.vk.sdk.api.model.VKList cannot be
>   cast to com.vk.sdk.api.model.VKUsersArray
>                                                                               at
>   com.example.gukov.testvk.MainActivity$1$1.onComplete(MainActivity.java:57)
>                                                                               at com.vk.sdk.api.VKRequest$3.run(VKRequest.java:482)
>                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
>                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                               at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
>                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)

Если заменить VKUsersArray на VKList, то VKApiUserFull перестает работать (подчеркивает красным). Что написать вместо VKApiUserFull?

Answer (score 1):

Согласно [en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22604204/3212712) надо так:

```
//Get user info
VKApi.users().get().executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
        VKApiUser user = ((VKList<VKApiUser>)response.parsedModel).get(0);
        Log.d("User name", user.first_name + " " + user.last_name);
    }
});
```